# Who first spoke of Euclidean domains?

Tags: reference-request, abstract-algebra

I am looking at Euclidean domains for the first time and it is a subject that has caught my attention. I wonder, who was the first to talk about this? I've been reading a little and so far the oldest definition I've seen is that of Van der Waerden, but I don't really know who introduced these ideas and definitions. In advance I appreciate any information you can give me

Comment: The name or the concept? Euclidean algorithm goes back to Pythagoreans, but was only so named c. 1900. Gauss developed typical methods for Euclidean domains in his work on Gaussian integers a century earlier, but not in abstract form. In the 19th century abstractization of ring theory is most associated with Dedekind and Kronecker. Van der Waerden merged "Euclidean" with "integral domain" that he took from Emmy Noether (as many other ideas in his Algebra). On the history of that see [Where does the term "integral domain" come from? on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/46026/152568)